# Primary key of a table starting with 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table 'rack' where on inserting the first values, the primary_key(column name:**rack_db_key**) gets the value '0'. 
Although the primary key is initialized as identity(1,1) still the values are starting from 0.

*What can I do to make it start from 1*?

Comment: If you care about the numeric value of these identifiers, you're using them wrong. You should treat them as opaque blobs that happen to fit in numeric columns. They should only be used to uniquely identify rows in the table and shouldn't ever be shown to users - so why does it matter *what* values they take on?

Comment: you should check if any trigger ,constraint define on that table.use sp_help tablename to check

Answer (score 0):

set your primary key column initial value to 1 (I hope rack_db_key is auto increment column)

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT = 1";
```

if your column rack_db_key is not auto increment than you can set it up with below query

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD rack_db_key INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ADD INDEX (rack_db_key);";
```

Comment: I have tried that. It doesn't make a difference. The auto_increment is initialised to 1 when the table was created.

Comment: share your insert query and table structure

Comment: use this query to describe your table "SHOW cretae table your_table"

Answer (score 0):

It may be because:

You may have truncate the table "rack" and then applied `dbcc checkident(rack,reseed,0)`

But in SQL whenever you truncate a table, it reseed it to 0 (automatically).

Hence u should use `dbcc checkident(rack,reseed,0)` only when you have `delete` the table.